# Gap after removing header of website in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

Hello I'm opening a website which has header in UIWebView. I'm removing that header with below code. It's removing header but It doesn't move next item to top. It shows a blank padding in the place of headers view.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "$(document).ready(function() { $('div.header').remove(); })")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by sending another javascript code to webpage;

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].style.paddingTop = '0px';")
```